# how to create sequences, from dataframe begin to every index, efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sampling

I have a timeseries dataframe, from which i would like to generate sequences.

```
Time                           A            B           C             D                                                               
2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71      
2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91      
2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41      
2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11      
2019-06-17 08:53:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.61      12503.61      
2019-06-17 08:54:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.11      12503.11
```

expected outcome is:
(As you can see the samples get longer, always start from the beginning, but end at the next row.
Note: I only left the indices inside, to clarify. They should not have to be in the outcome).

```
[                                                                                  
   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71  ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91   ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21   ],   

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41   ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21    ], 

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11    ], 

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    ],

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    ],  

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:53:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.61      12503.61     ],   

   [2019-06-17 08:45:00     12089.89     12089.89    12087.71      12087.71     
   2019-06-17 08:46:00     12087.91          NaN    12087.71      12087.91    
   2019-06-17 08:47:00     12088.21     12088.21    12084.21      12085.21      
   2019-06-17 08:48:00     12085.09     12090.21    12084.91      12089.41     
   2019-06-17 08:49:00     12089.71     12090.21    12087.21      12088.21     
   2019-06-17 08:50:00     12504.11     12504.11    12504.11      12504.11     
   2019-06-17 08:51:00     12504.11          NaN    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:52:00     12504.11     12504.11    12503.11      12503.11    
   2019-06-17 08:53:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.61      12503.61     
   2019-06-17 08:54:00     12503.61     12503.61    12503.11      12503.11  ]
                                                                               ]
```

How to do that?

Comment: Why do you want this? Surely it will be easier to work with the original dataframe and create a rolling (or expanding) window on the index.

Comment: Do you have an example? for the rolling/expanding window

Comment: It depends on what you plan to do with this, you need to explain that. Your question seems like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `np.asarray` or `DataFrame.values`, it is faster

```
arr = np.asarray(df)
#arr = df.values
result = [arr[:i] for i in range(1, df.shape[0]+1)]
```

Or

```
arr = np.asarray(df)
#arr = df.values
result = list(map(lambda i: arr[:i], range(1, df.shape[0]+1)))
```

---

```
%%timeit
arr = np.asarray(df)
result = list(map(lambda i: arr[:i], range(1,df.shape[0]+1)))
24 µs ± 1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Without `np.asarray`

```
%%timeit
result = list(map(lambda i: df[:i], range(1,df.shape[0]+1)))
935 µs ± 37.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

You could also try `DataFrame.shift`, but it is slow

```
%%timeit
n = df.shape[0]
[df.shift(i).dropna().values for i in reversed(range(n))]
15.8 ms ± 1.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**EDIT**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(500000, 4))


%%timeit
arr = np.asarray(df)
[arr[:i] for i in range(1, df.shape[0]+1)]

213 ms ± 16.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: how time efficient would this be for a dataframe of around 500.000 or 1 mio rows ?  24 µs ± 1 µs* 5000 (or 10000) linear or exponential longer?